# How to log on the server part in a GWT project

Tags: java, gwt, logging

I have a GWT project. I use standard Logger for the client side and server side logging. I created two Logger classes which inherit from java.util.logging.Logger. Client part works properly. The problem is on the server part. I have a logger class like:

```
public class ServerLogger extends Logger {

public ServerLogger() throws SecurityException, IOException {
    super("ServerLog", null);
    boolean append = true;
    FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler("My.log", append);
    fileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    addHandler(fileHandler);
}
}
```

But it does not create any log file and it does not log anything?? (The file should stay on the server part.)

How should I log on the server part??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with GWT. This is just logging in java.

There are many solutions to do this, but since you mentioned java.util.Logging here is a good blogpost on how to get started with java.util.logging in a servlet container:
http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/logging.jspx

Comment: You're right. I found the logging files. They were in `target-->www` folder in Eclipse.